# How to select submit button inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I tried to select the submit **button** in a form

```
<div id="container" class="f_forms with_f_style">
  <form id="form_fm" class="f-show-form" method="post">
    <h3>Short Registration</h3>
    <div class="f_form_fields">feild here</div>
    <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Above is the code for form.
Here is the code I tried

```
#container.f_forms with_f_style .submit input[type="submit"]
```

But what ever style I apply to that button is not happening. So I'm not selecting it correctly. Any help?

Comment: try adding . before with_f_style

Comment: give the button a class, and target it straightaway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have one more space and left a class selector in `with_f_style`

```
#container.f_forms with_f_style .submit input[type="submit"]
```

Use this:

```
#container.f_forms.with_f_style .submit input[type="submit"]
```

Comment: Thanks but its not happening when i inspect with firebug am getting another class.if i apply css there then these are happening `#container.f_forms.with_f_style .submit input[type="submit"], .f_form_submit_style `

Comment: Why don't you use just #container .submit input[type="submit"]

Comment: Sorry some typo and mess around But got it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 #container.f_forms.with_f_style .submit input[type="submit"]
```

If you want to select an element with multiple class, then use like

```
$('.classA.classB')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in selector, try this:

```
#container.f_forms.with_f_style .submit input[type="submit"]
```

But the problem may not be the selector. If you share what you do to style, we can check that.

Answer (score 0):

Target submit button using any container id which contains submit button.

```
#form_fm input[type="submit"]
```